# Change layout/orientation of json file to {key: [v1, v2], …} from {key: {index_1, v1, index_2, v2}}

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

`data = np.array([['val1', 'val2'], ['val3', 'val4']])
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['key1', 'key2'])

I need to conver it into json.

By default the outout looks like:

`{"key1":{"0":"val1","1":"val3"},"key2":{"0":"val2","1":"val4"}}` 
`
I need it in the following layout.

`{'key1':['val1','val2'],'key2':['val3','val4']}`

I have looked up the option on [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) and none of them give me the desired output.

Comment: Do you simply want `out = dataFrame.to_dict('list')`?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) and [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps):

```
import json

out = json.dumps(dataFrame.to_dict(orient='list'))
```

Output: `'{"key1": ["val1", "val3"], "key2": ["val2", "val4"]}'`